# Getting 'cannot find symbol' error

Tags: java

I am getting cannot find symbol error. I am making a program that could perform various mathematical operations. I am getting the error here:

```
a=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
```

The error is:

```
cannot find symbol- method readLine()
```

I am giving my whole program:

```
// I(Rachit Bhargava) am writing my first program that includes almost every feature of Mathematical Operations.
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class All_In_One
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(read);
        double a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, i1, a1, i2, a2;
        char ch1, ch2;
        System.out.println("To which topic is your question based upon?");
        System.out.println("Enter 'm' for Mathematics and 'g' for Geometry");
        System.out.println("Please enter your choice.");
        ch1= (char)(in.read());
        switch (ch1)
        {
            case 'm':
            System.out.println("What operation do you want to do?");
            System.out.println("Enter 'a' for addtion, 's' for subtraction, 'm' for multiplication, 'd' for division, 't' for finding out simple interest(with amount), 'c' for finding out compound interest(with amount) and 'b' for finding out both(with amount) and their difference");
            System.out.println("Please enter your choice.");
            ch2= (char)(in.read());
            switch (ch2)
            {
                case 'a':
                System.out.println("Please enter first number.");
                a=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Please enter second number.");
                b=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                c = a+b;
                System.out.println("Sum = "+c);
                break;
                case 's':
                System.out.println("Please enter first number.");
                a=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Please enter second number.");
                b=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                c = a-b;
                System.out.println("Difference = "+c);
                break;
                case 'm':
                System.out.println("Please enter first number.");
                a=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Please enter second number.");
                b=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                c = a*b;
                System.out.println("Answer = "+c);
                break;
                case 'd':
                System.out.println("Please enter first number.");
                a=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Please enter second number.");
                b=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                c = (a>b)? (a/b):(b/a);
                System.out.println("Answer = "+c);
                break;
                case 't':
                System.out.println("Please enter principal");
                p=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Please enter rate of interest.");
                r=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Please enter time(in years)");
                t=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                i = p*r*t/100;
                a = p+i;
                System.out.println("Simple interest = "+i);
                System.out.println("Amount = "+a);
                break;
                case 'c':
                System.out.println("Please enter principal");
                p=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Please enter rate of interest.");
                r=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Please enter time(in years)");
                t=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                a = p*(Math.pow(((100+r)/100), t));
                i = a-p;
                System.out.println("Compound Interest = "+i);
                System.out.println("Amount = "+a);
                break;
                case 'b':
                System.out.println("Please enter principal");
                p=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Please enter rate of interest.");
                r=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Please enter time(in years)");
                t=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                i1 = p*r*t/100;
                a1 = p+i1;
                a2 = p*(Math.pow(((100+r)/100), t));
                i2 = a-p;
                d = a2-a1;
                System.out.println("Simple interest = "+i1);
                System.out.println("Amount(as by simple interest) = "+a1);
                System.out.println("Compound Interest = "+i2);
                System.out.println("Amount(as by compound interest) = "+a2);
                System.out.println("Difference in interests and amount = "+d);
                break;
                default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input :(");
            }
            break;
            case 'g':
            System.out.println("Work In Progress!");
            break;
            default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Input :(");
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for using my program");
        System.out.println("All credits goes to Rachit Bhargava");
    }
}
```

Please help me solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do the following 2 changes:

1. ```
   InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
   BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(in);
   ```
2. Use read.readLine() rather than in.readLine();
   such as,

   a=Double.parseDouble(read.readLine());

Answer (score 0):

[InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) class does not have `readLine` method . [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is a better alternative to collect user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As you may see in [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) javadoc, there's no `readLine` method. Maybe you want to use the `readLine` method from your `BufferedReader read` variable since [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) **has** this method:

```
b = Double.parseDouble(read.readLine());
```

By the way:

- This line:

  ```
  BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(read);
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(in);
  ```

  The fact that compiles doesn't mean it will work as expected.
- I would recommend you changing the name of your variables for something more meaningful, for example `buffReader` instead of `read`, `firstNumber` instead of `a`, `secondNumber` instead of `b`, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Well that's because `InputStreamReader` doesn't have a `readLine()` method. You need to use `BufferedReader`

Change your code:

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(read);
```

to:

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(in);
```

Then you can do the following:

```
a = Double.parseDouble(read.readLine());
```

Alternatively you can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) which will allow you to do `Scanner.nextDouble()`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double a = scanner.nextDouble();
```